# How to install libsvm?

Tags: python, pycharm, svm, libsvm

I am having this issue.

```
import svm
import svmutil
from svm import *
```

It's telling me that "svmutil" isn't found. I am using the svm lib for my project on sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libsvm
```

Comment: Yes, just like you will normally install something on Linux.  If you are using windows the commands will be different.

Comment: Error message: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apt-get (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for apt-get.

Comment: What os do you have install ?  Like what distribution?